# Framework not found FIRAnalyticsConnector from Xcode 12.4

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

Getting "Framework not found FIRAnalyticsConnector" error after pod update in Xcode 12.4. I have cleaned and rebuild the project but It stays in there. What should I do?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Go to your project's target `Build Settings` > Search `FIRAnalyticsConnector` .

You will see `Other Linker Flags`.

Remove these lines below:

```
-framework
"FIRAnalyticsConnector"
```

Now, It should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for this! With regards to Firebase frameworks I also encountered additional ones so had to also remove GTMSessionFetcher, GoogleToolBoxForMac. But doing the same thing resolves it.

Comment: You can't delete it with backspace button, you need to click on "-" button, just keep it in mind