# After Cocoapod update: "No such file or directory: 'FirebaseAnalytics'"

Tags: xcode, firebase-cloud-messaging, cocoapods, linker-flags

I'm getting this error after updating the Firebase pods on Xcode 12.5.1, everything was working fine before `clang: error: no such file or directory: 'FirebaseAnalytics'`

[image]

It started after I deleted the linker flag as described below. Initially I was getting a `Framework not found FIRAnalyticsConnector` error, so I followed the solution from here (with image below): [Framework not found FIRAnalyticsConnector from Xcode 12.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66041725/framework-not-found-firanalyticsconnector-from-xcode-12-4)

[image]

So I deleted the `FIRAnalyticsConnector` Linker flag as described, it got rid of the previous error but then after that I get the `clang: error: no such file or directory: 'FirebaseAnalytics'` error.

Here's my targets:

[image]

And when I click on add dependencies the `FirebaseAnalytics` is greyed out:

[image]

So my question is how do I fix the `clang: error: no such file or directory: 'FirebaseAnalytics'` error? Thanks.

---

Comment: Try `pod deintegrate` and `pod update`